# How to make a smooth animation of two elements?

Tags: css, vue.js, animation

I wanted to make it so that when I click the **.add-todo** button, the input form (**.new-todo**) is also animated, but for some reason it seems that only the **.new-todo** form has animation, and when the input form appears, then the button goes down sharply and **I need it to go down smoothly** like an input form

Thanks in advance

[video of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHtb.gif)

```js
<script setup>
...
let isAddingTodo = ref(false)
</script>

<transition name="fade">
  <div
   v-if="isAddingTodo"
   class="new-todo p-3 border border-2 border-secondary rounded-3 mt-2 mb-2 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
  >
    ...
  </div>
</transition>

<div
 class="add-todo p-3 d-flex rounded-3 mb2 border border-2 border-white"
 @click="isAddingTodo = !isAddingTodo"
>
  <i class="fi fi-br-plus mx-auto"></i>
</div>

<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-69px);
}
</style>
```

I expected the button to also go down smoothly, but for some reason, when the form appears, it goes down sharply

Answer (score 0):

When your `newTodo` is visible it immediately takes up the available space before the animation completes, hence the jump on the button below that space.

Try giving the transition a fixed height before and after to match the transform:

```html
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 0;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-69px);
  height: 69px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks friend, although you made a mistake in the code, but your advice helped me partially. This is what I did:
```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 69px !important;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-69px);
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

The fact is that the internal elements can no longer be reduced
Perhaps we will consider some other options for correcting this problem?

Comment: can you consider other options? @paddyfields